# Pass right-click target to context sensitive application in right-click menu

Tags: windows-7, powershell, batch-file, context-menu

I want to make a right-click context menu option in Windows 7 that is context sensitive and can pass the name of the specific file/folder to a shell script.

I know this must be possible- for example if you've got a 7zip file you can right click on it, and then say "Extract here" and somehow the target (the .7z archive) is passed to the 7zip program.

In particular, I have a script that takes a .c file and stuffs it inside a LaTeX listing and runs pdflatex to make nicely formatted files to read. However, I've got to specify the file as a command line argument. What I'd like to do is make it so I can right click on a file and run this script automatically, passing the path of the right click target into the command line argument automatically.

Comment: Start command prompt and type `ftype /?` and `assoc /?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SuperUser!

This is going to require registry editing to accomplish, and it depends on if you want to add this item for all files, files of a specific extension only, folders, or both.

Open your registry editor and navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. You'll see a bunch of file extensions in here - this is what controls the context menu.

Adding a handler is the same process regardless of what you're attaching that menu item to, it just matters where you put it in the registry.

The process is as follows:

1. Create a new key under the `shell` key of thing you're adding to.
2. if you want this menu item to have an icon, add a string named `Icon` to the key you just created, with a path to the icon as the value.
3. Add a key **under** the item you created called `command`
4. Modify the (Default) entry under this key to point to the script you want to open, adding a `"%1"` wherever the filename being passed to the program should go in its command line.

As to where this new menu item should go? If you want it to show...

- for all files of a certain extension, put it under the matching extension key (you can create one if it does not exist).
- for all files everywhere, put it under the `*` key
- for all directories, put it under the `Directory` key.

Comment: It's crazy that the "%1" thing isn't documented anywhere I can find, even though I know what I'm looking for now. There are other symbols I see in some registry keys ("%L" or "%n") that I have no idea what they mean. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `%1` pass short names to 16 bit programs and long names to 32/64 bit programs. `%L` pass a long name to any program. As you can't run 16 bit programs anymore they are effectively the same. This was how windows handled compatibility of new long file name aware program with older programs.